# Enable Safari extension by script

Tags: python, macos, applescript

Good day!

I am looking for solution to enable Safari extension by script. I read few docs about it, but did not find any ideas to perform it.

I write in python, but any ideas will fit me. Applescript also.

Actually, if you have not solutions like "take and use", but have an ideas how to do this, I will be happy to hear it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I found script/command that can allow me to do it, but it doesn't works for me. Here:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari ExtensionsEnabled 1
```

On Safari 13.1.2 (Catalina, 10.15.6)

Comment: Was Safari running when you tried this script? Writing to defaults won't generally work if the app is running (an app usually keeps its defaults in memory and writes them back out to disk when it quits). For this to have any chance of working you have to quit Safari first, *then* write to defaults.

Comment: Addendum: I'm not sure this is relevant to Safari 13.1.2 (Catalina). I don't see a single button that enables or disables extensions; extensions are enabled and disabled on a case-by-case basis.  I'm not certain where that information is being stored (it may be in the database down in ~/Library/Safari/Databases).

Comment: Hi! Just saw your answers. First of all, thank you!
Safari was closed, of course, but there is no difference in results. I still can't enable extension.

Comment: You wrote about case-by-case basis. I want to enable certain extension, have you got any ideas about it? Only one extension, and I know all the credentials of it.